# Dash route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a simple route like this :

```
Route::get('/{name}-{id}', function($name, $id){
    return view('hello', compact('name', 'id'));
});
```

I have a URL : `example.com/hello-world-1234`
Laravel have a problem when processing this route. It detect "hello" as `name` and "world-1234" as `id`.

That does not happen if I used htaccess to route :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ hello.php?name=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

htaccess detect correctly "hello-world" as `name` and "1234" as `id`.
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this as your code. It should correctly identify name and id as you wanted it.

```
    Route::get('/{name}-{id}', function($name, $id){
    return view('hello', compact('name', 'id'));
})->where(['name' => '^([^\/]+)', 'id' => '([^\/]+)\/?$']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of regex `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints`,
but your`id` is not fixed, as on `id` =`world-1234` , I think it's hard to do this, can you replace `-` with`.`?